# Наследование в PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php
class User{
public $name;
public $login;
public $password;

function __construct($name,$login,$password){
    echo "Имя: $name <br>";
    echo "Логин: $login ";
    echo "<br> Пароль: $password <br><br>";
}
function _destruct(){
    echo "delete";
}
}

class SuperUser extends User{
public $role = "Ялта";

$object = new SuperUser("Super Admin",”root",”pass@word1"):
$object->role;

$obj1 = new User("Пушкин", "Pisatel", "111");
$obj1 = new User("Клоун", "Santa", "555");
$obj1 = new User("Жираф", "yra", "888");
unset($obj1);

?>
```

1. Почему вызов свойства `$object->role;` не выводит на экран значение свойства "Ялта"?
2. Как это можно передавать 3 аргумента из класса потомка, если в классе-потомке не создан конструктор с 3 аргументами и вообще никакой конструктор не создан в классе-потомке?

Comment: @romantik2011 Используйте текст вместо картинок.

Answer (score 2):

> > Почему вызов свойства $object->role; не выводит на экран значение свойства "Ялта"?

Потому что команда вывода - "echo"

> > Как это можно передавать 3 аргумента из класса потомка если в классе-потомке не создан конструктор с 3 аргументами и вообще никакой конструктор не создан в классе-потомке?

Потому что конструктор создан в классе-родителе и унаследован потомком.